# Combatipility issues with Swift 3 and Cocoapods packages

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire, swift3, swifty-json, haneke

I am stuck after updating `xCode` to version 8 with my already existing apps.

I used the following pods:

- Alamofire
- SwiftyJSON
- HanekeSwift
- PagedHorizontalView
- Intercom

I need help updating the **Podfile** so it will install **Swift 3 compatible** version of these packages.

I checked everywhere online and couldn't solve it yet :(

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Your podfile content if posted here would be appreciated as well.

Comment: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'ResalApp' do
 pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
 pod 'SwiftyJSON', git: 'https://github.com/BaiduHiDeviOS/SwiftyJSON.git', branch: 'swift3'
 pod 'HanekeSwift'
 pod 'PagedHorizontalView'
 pod 'Intercom'
end

Answer (score 0):

As per Alamofire documentation: CocoaPods 1.1.0+ is required to build Alamofire 4.0.0+.
To get latest version run: sudo gem install cocoapods --pre